# ASP.NET Replace a double quote with html number

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically I am trying to do that following

```
InputString = InputString.Replace(""", "&#34;");
```

But getting an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to escape double quotes in string like this

```
InputString = InputString.Replace("\"", "&#34;");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotation mark:

```
InputString = InputString.Replace("\"","&#34;");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to HTML Encode a String.  If you want to be 100% safe and not run into similar problems later with other characters, try:

```
public static string HtmlEncode( string text ) {
    char[] chars = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode( text ).ToCharArray();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder( text.Length + (int)( text.Length * 0.1 ) );

    foreach ( char c in chars ) {
        int value = Convert.ToInt32( c );
        if ( value > 127 )
            result.AppendFormat("&#{0};",value); 
        else
            result.Append( c );
    }

    return result.ToString();
}

InputString = HtmlEncode(InputString);
```

from: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/htmlencodingcsharp.aspx